# Web Scraping with Python - Satellites

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get data on satellite positions several times a day from https://www.n2yo.com/. The satellite I'm focused on is MUOS 5. My problem is I'm not able to get to any of the data changing in the table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
info = soup.find('div', class_='container-main')
info = info.find('div', id='trackinginfo')
info = info.find('div', id='paneldata')
info = info.find('table', id='tabledata')
info = info.find('tr')
print(info)
```

I expect to see the information shown and in the second column, 41622, But I don't know how to only access the second td

```
<tr>
<td>NORAD ID:</td><td><div id="noradid"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get `41622` from?  The only `id="noradid"` I see is `255444`.

Comment: On https://www.n2yo.com/?s=41622 for NoRAD ID do you not see 41622?

Comment: I do now; the link in the question didn't have `s=41622`. So what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: On that webpage is about a dozen dynamic numbers I'd like to capture each hour (longitude, latitude, etc.). If I can capture the ID, I'll know how to capture the rest of the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not a complete answer, but I believe it will get you started.

The page you linked to is dynamically loaded with javascript, so beautifulsoup can't handle it. The data itself is located at another url (see below - can be located through the Developer tab in your browser) and, since it's in json format, it can be loaded into python.

The json contains historical information, and the most recent item is located at the end of the json string. Once you have that, you can extract the relevant data from it.

As you'll see below, I managed to connect some of the dynamic data to some of the types, but I'm not really familiar with the terminology, so you will probably have to do some extra work to complete it. But, as I said, it will at least get you started:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://www.n2yo.com/sat/instant-tracking.php?s=41622&hlat=40.71427&hlng=-74.00597&d=300&r=547647090737.1928&tz=GMT-04:00&O=n2yocom&rnd_str=8fde3fd56c515d8fb110d5145c7df86b&callback=')
data = json.loads(req.text)

heads = ['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE', 'AZIMUTH','ELEVATION','??','DECLINATION','ALTITUDE [km]','???','NORAD ID','ABC','xxx'] #as I said, not sure exactly what's what...    
target = list(data[0].values())[-1][-1] #this is the most recent data
dats = [item for item in list(target.values())[0].split('|')]
for v,d in zip(dats,heads):
    print(d,':',v)
```

Output:

```
LATITUDE : -6.18764033
LONGITUDE : -102.54010579
AZIMUTH : 216.12
ELEVATION : 28.65
?? : 242.47221474
DECLINATION : -12.92722520
ALTITUDE [km] : 35625.07
??? : 0.19091700104938
NORAD ID : 41622
ABC : 1598058725
xxx : 0
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if I can make this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. You are looking for data on this page: https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=41622

For the reason that in my opinion the HTML is not "made for BeautifulSoup", I would recommend regular expressions

... </ul></p><br/><B>NORAD ID</B>: 41622 <a  ...

```
m = re.search(r'\<B\>NORAD ID\<\/B\>: (.*?) \<a', read_data)
print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Not exactly that slide. If you click track satellite, up pops this webpage (https://www.n2yo.com/?s=41622) which gives real time data.

Comment: On this page all data are provided via Javascript <script src="/js/n2yo4.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. Beautiful Soup does not run the java script provided with the website. I guess you should try something like this: https://pythonprogramming.net/javascript-dynamic-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see if I can get it working.